# Help identifying adapter DC plug

Tags: dc, identification, plug

Does anyone know what type of plug type this is? I am having no luck identifying it so far. The closest I have found are the Kycon KPPX-3P-SR7DI but it only comes in a 3 and 4 pole version and this plug only has two pins?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Comment: are you certain that there is not a broken off pin? ... that looks like a power plug for an Epson printer ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=epson+printer+power+plug&iar=images&ia=images&iax=images

Comment: Yes I am 100% certain. That Epson plug looks like the Kycon KPPX-3P-SR7DI. My plug is originally for the new AT&T fiber router and you can see on the back that the receptacle only has two holes as well. https://www.amazon.com/802-11a-Wireless-ax-Integrated-Residential-Replaces/dp/B08PCRYJPW

Comment: Ok sorry I did not know that, I will remove that part.

Comment: It looks like a non-standard variant of a mini-DIN plug.